# ソケット通信のエラーについて

Tags: c++, socket, boost

### 現状の問題点

ノートPCとデスクトップPC間でソケット通信を行い，動画転送のアプリケーションを作成しています．仕組みの都合上，サーバは常に待機状態，クライアントは設定したタイミングでサーバに接続要求し，接続後にデータを送ります．クライアントをデスクトップPC，サーバをノートPCにしているのですが，ソケット通信接続の段階でエラーが起こってしまいます．同じような現象を経験した方がいましたらご教授お願い致します．

### 環境

- ノートPC：Surface, Windows8
- デスクトップPC：DELL, Windows7
- ルータ：Cisco
- 言語：C++，Boost Library (asioなど使用)
- ファイアウォール：Off
- F-Secure

### エラーメッセージ

「対象のコンピュータによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした」

### 試したこと

- 役割が逆，すなわちノートPCがクライアントであればこの問題は回避できることを確認
- 自作アプリではなく，Apacheサーバを立てて同じことをやった．結果，ノートPC側がサーバになる場合デスクトップPCからアクセスできなかった．
- Wiresharkで上記Apache作戦を実行時のパケットを見たが，3ウェイハンドシェイク時の**ノートPC側（サーバ）からのACK**が届いていない．ノートPCがクライアントの場合は3ウェイハンドシェイクは成功

Comment: F-Secureは、どこ(どのマシン）にインストールされていて、どのような設定がされているのでしょうか？　3way handshakeは、Syn(Client -> Server),Syn-Ack(Server->Client)、ACK(Client->Server)というステップになる。質問に書かれている”PC側（サーバ）からのACK”というのは、Syn-Ackの事？　それとも、3Way handshakeのプロトコルが一般のものとは異なるのでしょうか？？？

Answer (score 1):

問題切り分けのためには、シンプルな環境を用意して、
1つ1つ考えられる原因を潰していくのが良いと思います。

物理的に以下のような構成になっているのだと思いますので、

```
ノートPC - ルータ - デスクトップPC
```

考えられそうな主な原因は、以下だと思いました。

- 1) クライアントアプリ,サーバーアプリの設定誤りやバグなど
- 2) OS内で、他のアプリがポートを使用済み
      (netstatなどで確認できます。)
- 3) OS内でファイアウォール、セキュリティソフトが通信を遮断
      (ファイアウォールやセキュリティソフトを無効かすることで確認できます。)
- 4) ルータが通信を遮断

問題切り分けのためには、
ルータが影響しない環境(ノートPCとデスクトップPCをハブにつなぐなど..)を用意し、
通信ができるか確認する必要があると思います。
この環境で、通信できない場合は、1)〜3)が原因ではないか確認してください。

この環境で問題なく通信ができれば、
4)が原因だと思いますので、ルータの設定を確認してください。